# Identify these astronauts

Tags: space-shuttle, astronauts

In December 2017 former astronaut Janet Kavandi [tweeted](https://twitter.com/janetkavandi/status/946434732509810688) a picture of a  group of women astronauts taken at an astronaut reunion.

There are nine of them I can't identify, can anyone name them?  I've annotated the picture to show the ones I don't know.

[image]

Comment: #7 might be Nicole Aunapu Mann

Comment: @BretCopeland I think you are right. Consider posting an answer, partial answers are fine.

Comment: Fair enough. Done. I'd really love to see you caption all of the people you _do_ recognize! I only recognize a small handful, but I've never met any of them either.

Comment: @BretCopeland Good idea! I don't want to clutter the picture up with more numbers, but eventually I'll post an answer with everybody numbered and ID/d.  The ones I don't know appear to be from before and after my time in Spaceflight Training (Nicole Mann being an example of after). The other ones I either recognize or have been fortunate enough to have worked with.

Comment: This site has suggestions for each person that look pretty legit, if someone wants to take a crack at it. You have to scroll down the thread to get to the picture from the OP. http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum38/HTML/002068.html

Comment: @called2voyage good find, those agree with the ones I recognize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Shannon Lucid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_Lucid)
2. [Jenni Sidey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenni_Sidey)
3. [Loral O'Hara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loral_O%27Hara)
4. [Zena Cardman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zena_Cardman)
5. [Kayla Barron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayla_Barron)
6. [Jessica Watkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Watkins)
7. [Nicole Aunapu Mann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Aunapu_Mann)
8. [Kathryn D. Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathryn_D._Sullivan)
9. [Mary Ellen Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Ellen_Weber)

Credits:

- Nicole Mann was identified by looking at Wikipedia's [list of female spacefarers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_spacefarers).
- 3 through 6 were identified via NASA's [Astronaut Candidates page](https://www.nasa.gov/astronauts/biographies/candidates), which @CourageousPotato discovered.
- The remaining astronauts were identified by Robert Pearlman and "Delta7" in a 2017 [collectspace.com](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum38/HTML/002068.html) post which @called2voyage discovered.

Complete Caption:

> **Back Row** (left to right): Jenni Sidey, Stephanie Wilson, Ellen Ochoa, Jasmin Moghbeli, Loral O’Hara, Peggy Whitson, Janet Kavandi, Nicole Stott, Zena Cardman, Kate Rubins, Kayla Barron
>
> **Front Row** (left to right): Eileen Collins, Shannon Lucid, Rhea Seddon, Karen Nyberg, Lisa Nowak, Sandy Magnus, Joan Higginbotham, Bonnie Dunbar, Mary Ellen Weber, Kathy Sullivan, Megan McArthur Behnken, Barbara Morgan, Nicole Mann, Julie Payette, Cady Coleman, Jessica Watkins

Comment: Agree about the low res picture. Searches to find a better one were unsuccessful :(

Comment: Bret, I added a potentially helpful resource to the comments of the question.

Comment: @called2voyage awesome, I'll update this answer!

Comment: Thanks! Even though now I feel even more out of touch with the program. I've never really heard of these Group 21 and 22 people :(  And I would not have recognized Weber and Sullivan even though I've met them long ago.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that may be so, but I bet most of us wish we had even half the amount of first-hand experience with the human spaceflight program that you had. I mean, I gave a whole talk on how to land the shuttle... but I've never actually met anyone who did.

Answer (score 4):

3 looks like Loral O'Hara:

https://www.nasa.gov/astronauts/biographies/candidates

It looks like Wikipedia doesn't have the ASCANs up to date.

Comment: Rubins looks like the one standing next to #4, while #3 looks like Karen Nygard ???

Comment: @aml Looks like Wikipedia hasn't been updated. I edited my answer.

Comment: Great find! The picture on that page helped me identify three more of the people.

Comment: @amI I think Nygard is the one standing just below #2

Comment: If y'all mean Nyberg, yes, she's below #2.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yep, oops.